# JQuery Select2 Multiple Select Stutters on Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select control that I am using [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) on, however, when I load the page, it stutters...

First it looks like

[image: starting look]

Then it looks like

[image: final look]

How can I get it to look like the second image, without every looking like the first?

The code I am using is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function () {

    $('#faq-tags-tag').select2({
        tags: true
    });

});
</script>
```

When I try without document ready, it just looks like the first image...

Comment: It takes time for script to change default select. First you see default select and then it changes by script. You can use preloader to hide these things. Something like that https://codepen.io/mimoYmima/pen/fisgL.

Comment: It could be as simple as loading your `script` earlier.

Comment: I appreciate your response, I placed the jquery code in the head and it still happens, I may have to go with a loader if thats the best option

Answer (score 0):

You can try add `hidden` attribute to the `select` tag and test if the behavior is OK with you. Add `hidden` will prevent the `select` tag be shown when the HTML code is loaded, but then the jquery code which render the select2 will re-render the element without `hidden` attribute so the element will display as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `style="display: none;"` on your `select`. It should solve the problem of flicker.